# Using a ListBox locks out the other controls on the form

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have a form in a Windows application that contains several controls: radio buttons, command buttons, text boxes, a datagridview, and a ListBox.

The dataGridView is bound to a datatable and the ListBox is bound to another datatable.  I use the radio buttons and the ListBox to filter the contents of the dataGridView.

If I click on any of the radio buttons, the data in the Grid changes accordingly.  I can also click on the other controls and they respond as well.

I can also scroll through the ListBox without any problems.  But once I click on an item in the ListBox, the data grid is updated and continues to update with each item selected from the ListBox.  But all other controls are inactive, as if they are locked up.

What causes this and how do I fix it?

Here is the code:

```
    private void lstColor_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            viewLocalMatsALLBindingSource.Filter = "GRM_COLOR_DESCR = '" + lstColor.Text + "'";
    }

    private void rdbLogomat_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rdbLogomat.Checked)
        {
            viewLocalMatsALLBindingSource.Filter = "Description LIKE '%LOGO%' OR Description LIKE '%LO-GO%'";
        }
    }
```

The radio event works just fine and I can use the other controls on the form.  But the ListBox event causes all the other controls to freeze, even the red 'X' close button on the window.  However, after the selecting an item in the ListBox, I can select cells and rows in the datagrid.  But if I try typing anything in a cell, the ListBox selected item changes based on the characters I type.  (The datagrid is read only so editing cells is meaningless.)  So apparently the Listbox is maintaining focus but I can't figure out how to lose the focus.  Another thing is that I can sort on the columns in the datagrid until I select an item from the ListBox and then that function goes away.

Comment: Are you subscribing to any events of the listbox, such as item selected?

Comment: You'll have to post some code. What do you mean by 'locked up'? Do you mean they are responsive but don't change the data in the DataGridView? How are you editing the Data in the DataGridview?

Comment: show some code? specially the portion where you handle listbox item selection/click and rebind grid